# Collapsible rows in table without using any IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a table in which whenever a user clicks the row it expands its next hidden row. to do that I have used the below script in which the next element of the class `row-details` is targeted as a hidden element. The issue here is to use an id or class to target each div inside the row.

If I use normal div elements then the script can use `this.nextElementSibling;` to identify the next div element which can be hidden and when the first div is clicked it will expand.

```
var tableRow = document.getElementsByClassName('row');

for (var i = 0; i < tableRow.length; i++) {
    tableRow[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var tableContent = document.querySelector('.row-details');
        if (tableContent.style.maxHeight) {
            tableContent.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            tableContent.style.maxHeight = tableContent.scrollHeight + 'px';
        }
    });
}
```

In the below code there are 2 rows each with a hidden row containing details. I have used the same class for both hidden rows. What I am trying to achieve is to expand the hidden row without defining any Id or class. `min-height` property is not working on `tr` tags.

```js
var tableRow = document.getElementsByClassName('row');

for (var i = 0; i < tableRow.length; i++) {
    tableRow[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var tableContent = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (tableContent.style.maxHeight) {
            tableContent.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            tableContent.style.maxHeight = tableContent.scrollHeight + 'px';
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.row-details{
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

table {
  border-collapse: unset;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Data-1</th>
    <th>Data-2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>ipsum</td>
    <td>dolor sit amet.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="row-details">
        <span>Lorem, ipsum.</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>ipsum</td>
    <td>dolor sit amet.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="row-details">
        <span>Lorem, ipsum.</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Changed Code:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

    table.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let header_row = e.target.closest('tr.row');
        let details_row = header_row.nextElementSibling;
        details_row.classList.add('show');

        var tableContent = document.querySelector('tr.show .row-details');

        if (tableContent.style.maxHeight) {
            tableContent.style.maxHeight = null;
            details_row.classList.remove('show');
        } else {
            tableContent.style.maxHeight = tableContent.scrollHeight + 'px';
        }
    });
```

```css
.row-details {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}


table {
  border-collapse: unset;
}

tr.row {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Data-1</th>
    <th>Data-2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>ipsum</td>
    <td>dolor sit amet.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="row-details">
        <span>Lorem, ipsum.</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>ipsum</td>
    <td>dolor sit amet.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="row-details">
        <span>Lorem, ipsum.</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I just have one event listener for the entire table. When clicked, I find the [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) `tr.row` and toggle a class name on the `nextElementSibling`. With a selector I can then control the `<div>`.

If you are using the [max-height technique](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/#aa-technique-1-max-height) you can just put a max-height that is larger then the content.

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

table.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let header_row = e.target.closest('tr.row');
  let details_row = header_row.nextElementSibling;
  details_row.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
.row-details {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

tr.show .row-details {
  max-height: 3em;
}

table {
  border-collapse: unset;
}

tr.row {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Data-1</th>
    <th>Data-2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>ipsum</td>
    <td>dolor sit amet.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="row-details">
        <span>Lorem, ipsum.</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>ipsum</td>
    <td>dolor sit amet.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="row-details">
        <span>Lorem, ipsum.</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have made some changes to the script to calculate the height of row details based on the content size. But it is not working properly. It does not target the next element but targets the previous one.